# Unix Timestamp in Hive provide same results

Tags: date, hive, hadoop-yarn, unix-timestamp, hue

I am using Hive 1.2.1000. 
I am actually dealing with conversion to unix timestamp. I'm trying to convert a date with format:

> dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

to unix_timestamp, hence:

> unix_timestamp(date,"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")

have been used.

More precisely, I have run the following code:

> select '09/06/2012 04:02:32', regexp_replace('09/06/2012 04:02:32',"/","-")

which seems to work, in fact the result is: **1326081752**

I have also noticed that I have **N** distinct dates and the distinct on unix_timestamp of these dates is **M** with **M < N**.

Doing some manipulations on the data i have seen that there are different dates with the same unix_timestamp.

Hence i've tried to go deeper and i have found a lot of dates, for example

```
09/06/2012 04:02:32
```

and

```
09/12/2012 04:02:32
```

Now, if I try to run the following code:

```
select 
'09/06/2012 04:02:32', 
regexp_replace('09/06/2012 04:02:32',"/","-"),
unix_timestamp(regexp_replace('09/06/2012 04:02:32',"/","-"),"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss"), 
unix_timestamp('09-06-2012 04:02:32',"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
UNION ALL
select '09/12/2012 04:02:32', 
regexp_replace('09/12/2012 04:02:32',"/","-"), 
unix_timestamp(regexp_replace('09/12/2012 04:02:32',"/","-"),"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss"), 
unix_timestamp('09-12-2012 04:02:32',"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

That's the output:

```
09/06/2012 04:02:32 09-06-2012 04:02:32 1326081752  1326081752  1326081752
09/12/2012 04:02:32 09-12-2012 04:02:32 1326081752  1326081752  1326081752
```

Which is clearly the same.

This result can be extended for all the dates where everything is identical except one between **dd** and **mm**.

Could you explain me why?

Thanks in advance,
Manuel

Ps. I have also tried with dates with other format for example:

```
select '2012-06-09 04:02:32', unix_timestamp(regexp_replace('2012-06-09 04:02:32',"/","-"),"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
UNION ALL
select '2012-12-09 04:02:32', unix_timestamp(regexp_replace('2012-12-09 04:02:32',"/","-"),"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

But result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that **mm** stands for minutes.

> dd-**MM**-yyyy hh:mm:ss

instead of

> dd-**mm**-yyyy hh:mm:ss

was the solution to the problem.